# Restart killed process with SIGHUP

Tags: c++, linux, shell, fork, signals

I have a process and want to start it again when it is killed. To achieve this, I start child "guardian" process, that uses `prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGHUP);` to catch killing of its parent and starts it again.

Here is code of guardian (logging omitted):

```
void restart (int signal) {
    if (getppid() == 1) {
        if (fork() == 0) {
            execl("./process", 0);
        }
        exit(1);
    }
}

int main() {
    prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGHUP, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    struct sigaction new_action, old_action;
    new_action.sa_handler = restart;
    sigemptyset (&new_action.sa_mask);
    new_action.sa_flags = 0;

    sigaction (SIGHUP, NULL, &old_action);

    if (old_action.sa_handler != SIG_IGN) {
        sigaction (SIGHUP, &new_action, NULL);
    } 

    while (getppid() != 1) {
        sleep(86400000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And parent:

```
int main() {
    if (fork() == 0) {
        execl("./guardian", 0);
    } 
    while (1) {
        cout << "I am process\n";
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem I have is that it works just one time. Here is `ps` output when process was started first time:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
1012     13058  0.0  0.3  20244  1932 pts/1    Ss   08:22   0:00 -sh
1012     22084  0.0  0.1  11484  1004 pts/1    S+   11:20   0:00  \_ ./process
1012     22085  0.0  0.1  11484  1000 pts/1    S+   11:20   0:00      \_ [guardian]
1012     12510  0.0  0.3  20784  1712 pts/0    Ss   08:14   0:00 -sh
1012     22088  0.0  0.1  17412  1012 pts/0    R+   11:20   0:00  \_ ps fu
```

which looks good. Next I kill process with `kill -9 22084`. And again `ps` output:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
1012     13058  0.0  0.3  20244  1932 pts/1    Ss+  08:22   0:00 -sh
1012     12510  0.0  0.3  20784  1712 pts/0    Ss   08:14   0:00 -sh
1012     22091  0.0  0.1  17412  1012 pts/0    R+   11:21   0:00  \_ ps fu
1012     22089  0.0  0.1  11484   996 pts/1    S    11:20   0:00 [process]
1012     22090  0.0  0.1  11484   996 pts/1    S    11:20   0:00  \_ [guardian]
```

and when I kill process again `kill -9 22089` guardian does not seem to get SIGHUP callback (I checked from logs, they are omitted here).

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
1012     13058  0.0  0.3  20244  1932 pts/1    Ss+  08:22   0:00 -sh
1012     12510  0.0  0.3  20784  1712 pts/0    Rs   08:14   0:00 -sh
1012     22339  0.0  0.1  17412  1008 pts/0    R+   11:27   0:00  \_ ps fu
1012     22090  0.0  0.1  11484   996 pts/1    S    11:20   0:00 [guardian]
```

My question is - why guardian does not get SIGHUP?

I suspect it might have something to to with background process group - when process is restarted it is in background group (compare S+ and S in ps stat).

Comment: This is insane.  Instead of having a child restart the parent, why not just have the parent restart the child?  The whole system is setup so that doing that is trivial.

Comment: Yep I know this does not make too much sense. I am reproducing process restart logic that I have in my android application. Android starts app (parent process) and that process starts guardian (child process) which monitors health of parent.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Not so insane. My antivirus software apparently does something very similar. Killing the antivirus program is a standard hacker ploy, so the antivirus program creates multiple instances of itself and each of these creates a guardian that watch for a killed parent. Kill -9 is unblockable and undetectable -- in the application being killed, that is. It is detectable in child processes.

Comment: @David, but what is the advantage of having the child monitor the parent instead of having the parent monitor the child?  Having the parent monitor the child is trivial, and I see no advantage to bending over backwards to watch a parent.

Comment: The only advantage I can see is that it is (slightly) easier to get the parent pid than finding child pids, so the cracker can kill the parent easily.  But finding monitoring children is hardly difficult, and a security policy the relies on the adversary not being able to find pids of running children is pretty weak.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: "what is the advantage of having the child monitor the parent instead of having the parent monitor the child?" Kill -9. If the parent monitors the child (but not the other way around), killing the parent via kill -9 and then killing the child will circumvent the protection. A process cannot intercept a kill -9. There is no signal to the process. The process is just stopped in its tracks.

Comment: @David That's not an advantage.  Exactly the same situation occurs if the child is monitoring the parent and SIGKILL is sent to the child and then to the parent.

Comment: @David Forgive me for being obtuse.  I think what you are describing is having the child monitor the parent while the parent is still monitoring the child, so that if either takes a SIGKILL while the other is still running, it will be detected.    This does provide some added level of protection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `SIGHUP` is blocked while you are in the signal handler handling `SIGHUP`. `fork()` and `exec()` inherit the signal mask, hence your second guardian never receives it again.

Unblock `SIGHUP` while in the signal handler after `fork()` before `exec()` parent.

Comment: sigset_t x;
sigemptyset (&x);
sigaddset(&x, SIGHUP);
sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &x, NULL);